# PHP is not running correctly

Tags: python, php, selenium-webdriver

I want the user to enter keywords in the form. After the form is sent, php(exec) will deliver the keyword to python. Python will use selenium and wget modules to download pictures according to keywords, and then print true to php.

After the form is sent, python runs and finishes, but php doesn't work...
I found out that using webdriver in selenium, php won't work.How can I solve this problem?

I want:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afCTA.jpg)
→
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXn4i.jpg)
→
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efA8u.jpg)

result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xjrL.jpg)
→
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoHtB.jpg)
→
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5JdQ.jpg) (The form doesn't seem to be sent, but python gets executed.)

PHP:

```
<?php

    echo '<form action="" method="post">';   
        echo '<input type="text" name="keywords" placeholder="keywords">';
        echo '<input type="submit" value="search">';
    echo '</form>';

    


    if (isset($_POST['keywords'])) {
        
        $keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
        $get_value = exec("D:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python D:/xampp/htdocs/website_test/test.py {$keywords}", $output, $ret);

        
        if ($get_value == true) {
            echo 'Y'; 
        }else {
            echo 'N';
        }
        
    }

?>
```

PYTHON:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import os
import wget

import sys
import codecs



sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout.buffer, "strict")

path = "D:/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/") 

username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(    
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "KPnG0"))
)




#---log in FB---
login = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[5]/button/span[2]')
login.click()    

username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(    
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "email"))
)

password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(    
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "pass"))
)


login_FB = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="loginbutton"]')

username.clear()  
password.clear()  
username.send_keys('*********')

password.send_keys('******')

login_FB.click()   # log in bt



search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(    
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "XTCLo"))
)

keyword = sys.argv[1]

search.send_keys(keyword)   
time.sleep(1)   #wait 1s
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)   #enter
time.sleep(1)   
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)   #enter



time.sleep(5)   


WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(    
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "FFVAD"))
)



for i in range(5):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(5)


imgs = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="FFVAD")




path = os.path.join(keyword)
os.mkdir(path)   



#---download pic---
count = 0
for img in imgs:
    save_as = os.path.join(path, keyword + str(count) + '.jpg')
    wget.download(img.get_attribute("src"), save_as)
    count += 1


print("true")
```

Comment: `print("ture")`? Do you mean `print("true")`?

Comment: Yes!I forgot to modify.Thank you.

Comment: In your PHP code you have a `header()` after your form. `header()` must be called before any actual output is sent, or it might generate an error/warning.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I need to ask you a question.
Do I need to use header() if I use <meta charset="utf-8">?

Comment: Sorry, I was gone for a while. No, you don't need it if you code [a proper HTML page](https://codepen.io/rickgomez223/pen/ExxzbKG) and make the PHP file UTF-8.

Comment: That's OK. Now I try to remove the header(), but the result is the same and there is no error message.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to use
`def main():` and `if __name__ == '__main__':`
to wrap my code, then this problem has been solved.

Comment: But your question is called "**PHP** is not running correctly". How adding something the working python code can fix PHP?

Comment: I don't know what is root cause, but I modified by this way, the php code after executing python can be run successfully.